# Failure to transfer dependency, was cached in the local repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am working on maven 2 project on eclipse, and I have the m2e plugin, and I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
Failure to transfer com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:pom:1.3.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:pom:1.3.1 from/to central (http://
 repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to create a selector. to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/
 xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.pom
```

please advise how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `-U` switch to Maven?

Comment: While trying to figure out how `mvn -U` and Eclipse's "force update" work, I noticed that exactly this dependency (same version) still fails to download in Eclipse. Is there something special about `xstream-1.3.1`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem fixed after deleting the `.lastUpdated` file and the dependency then downloading it again.

Comment: how does it differ from "I followed answers on similar problem by removing .lastUpdated file then clean and build with no luck"?

Comment: And where is this file?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `-U` parameter to force a check for the updated releases and snapshots on remote
repositories, and resolve this issue.

Actually you can find this solution by using `mvn -h` to show Maven help.

Answer (score 3):

Error occured because of old cache of Maven tool is present in your directory.
So you must delete it.
Go to `C\User\"your user name"\m2` then delete it.

Comment: I found it good enough to delete `C:\Users\"your user name"\.m2\repository`. And not deleting `.m2` allowed me to leave my Maven proxy settings file `.m2\settings.xml` per [this article](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html), alone.

Comment: This is a very heavy handed approach.  It will delete your entire maven cache, and also likely your settings.xml file if you have one in `.m2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse:

- Go to `Window->Preferences->Maven`:
  check the download artifact source code, artifact javadoc, update maven project on startup.
- In the folder that contains `pom.xml`, run:
  `mvn clean install -U`

It worked for me :).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had multiple problems and I did the following to resolve the issue:

Locate the ***correct repository folder*** which my project is pointing to, then

1. Delete `_remote.repositories`
2. Delete `whatEverLib-x.x.x.jar.lastUpdated`
3. Delete `whatEverLib-x.x.x.pom.lastUpdated`

By default, maven will look at the settings in `settings.xml`.

4. Ensure I am using the correct `settings.xml` file.
5. Delete the unused repository from `~/.m2` which is not required where `~` is your home directory (for those who want to backup before deletion can do so)