# Maven cofiguration error in eclipse - git project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

While I am trying to use Maven this error occurs in Eclipse

> Failure to transfer commons-lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
>
> Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1 from/to
>   central  repo.maven.apache.org    pom.xml /test   line 1  Maven
>   Configuration Problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure to transfer dependency, was cached in the local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684311/failure-to-transfer-dependency-was-cached-in-the-local-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add many `<plugin>` into `<plugins>` tag, example show below :-

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
```