# Error in pom.xml file in eclipse webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications

I am getting following error message in `pom.xml` file, anyone please help me to solve this problem. I have searched the solution in google yet to get solution.

**ERROR**

```
Failure to transfer com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:pom:1.3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
 cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
 updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:pom:1.3.1 from/to 
 central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>helloworld Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: sorry please check now.

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685698/3143670

Comment: This problem is due to settings.xml is not defined properly. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2

Comment: I have checked that answer but where do i find .lastUpdated file

Comment: @OomphFortuity - which setting.xml? i think that is different question.

Comment: @karthikselvaraj on which location you have placed settings.xml?

Comment: @OomphFortuity - I don't have file like that

Comment: @karthikselvaraj this is the issue.Please configure your local repo https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Comment: @OomphFortuity - thanks for your command, finally I have fixed this issue by deleting com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream folder from local repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162087/discussion-between-karthik-selvaraj-and-oomph-fortuity).

Comment: I would say based on the error message you have either a firewall/proxy in front of the internet access which fails .. ` The operation was cancelled....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by deleting the corresponding failed to download artifact directory in my local repo. So that next time it will downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the problem in layman terms

1. one of the dependencies in the pom.xml is unable to be downloaded.
2. that's the reason it keeps on showing error whatever you try.
3. the solution is, identify the dependency and remove it from the pom.xml
4. Add it as a Jar file (if the dependency is mandatory, else just ignore the dependency)
5. tricky part is, you have to identify the correct dependency which shows the error.
   Hope this helps.
   ps: I am a noobie, I faced the similar issue and the above was the solution which worked for me. Thanks!